# What should be the good beginners project in cocoa to learn basics?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I had made iPlayer using NSSound class which is a music application as my dummy project in cocoa. I need to make another project which will help me to understand the basics of cocoa in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a three-part series on *Building a Cocoa Calculator Application with XCode 3 for Mac* on youtube:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuUgrxU6pYU